# How to open a file or buffer in a new tab without leaving the current one and without switching edit-modes?

Tags: vim

There got to be a way to open a newtab in background, without leaving the current tab, but i just can't find it in the docmentation.

Scenario: User Bob works on file: `foo.txt`. An external program updates periodically a file `bar.txt`. It then opens a new tab in the *background* of Bob's vim-session without forcing Bob to switch away from his current editing of `foo.txt` in his *foreground* tab.

All `tab*` commands doesn't seem to do the job. What am i missing?

You could say im looking for an equivalent to :`tabnew_in_background_leave_edit_mode_as_is()`.

Comment: Could you further explain what is the task of the "external program"? It is not clear why it should update it from inside Vim.

Comment: Then you could just leave the tab open in background to be accessed only by the user, and perform the updates without involving Vim. Why it is necessary to prepend data through Vim?

Comment: OK, no arguments when it came to "I want it to be this way". I thought your purpose was to have some task performed and was trying to point an easier way -- failed to understand that you are doing this way for fun. My bad.

Comment: Beg you pardon, but it's not "for fun". There's a very practical reason behind it and the question is quite simple. It's so trivial, i could have left it by the question in the title. Simple question - simple answer. That there may be no simple answer to it, is strongly indicated by comments which try to add a "different angle" to it. Implying that if there's no simple answer, the question has to be bogus!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
$ vim --servername BOB --remote-tab +":tabprevious" filename
```

***edit***

Vim has no command for opening a tab in the background. That's why we need the `:tabprevious` trick to open the new tab and go back to the previous one immediately. The drawback is that we are not in insert mode anymore.

Fortunately, we have `gi`, the normal mode mapping used to return to insert mode where it was last exited. This command works, here:

```
$ vim --servername BOB --remote-tab +":tabprevious" filename && vim --servername BOB --remote-send "gi"
```

Including and generalizing it in a shell script doesn't sound complicated.

Here is a second way, using the same ingredients but combined differently:

```
$ vim --servername BOB --remote-send "<Esc>:tabe filename | tabprevious<CR>gi"
```

Basically, we exit insert mode, do our "tab" business and get back to where we were. And we have another drawback: this method is tied to insert mode so we would end up in insert mode even if we were not there before.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to do that cleanly that doesn't involve writing a function.

Comment: That's ok, for me! If i have to write a function - so be it. I just didnt want to reinvent the wheel, because if was a blind mole. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

did you check `--remote-tab`? or I misunderstood your question?

in vim, type `:h remote-tab`

```
   --remote-tab         Like --remote but open each file in a new
                tabpage.
```

so you could try: (assume you had already a vim "server" named "SVR"):

```
vim --servername SVR --remote-tab foo.txt
```

the `foo.txt` will be opened in tab of `SVR` vim instance

Comment: this, opens a new tab in "foreground" = disrupts the workflow of the user. I search a way to open a tab in the background, while the user works on his current file without being disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing SHIFT + t when the cursor is over a filename in a directory listing opens the file in a background tab.